# How to train a svm with pandas dataframe having strings as target(y) and features(X) values?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I have a csv file having details of location, latitude, longitude, crime type etc.
I want to make a classifier such that it will predict the crime type given the other attributes.
Now, I want to train this using sklearn but sklearn requires float values.

```
    import os
    import glob
    import pandas as pd
    from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split
    from sklearn import svm
    from sklearn import preprocessing
    from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfTransformer

    input_file_name = []
    input_file = []
    frame = pd.DataFrame()
    fields = ['Reported by', 'Falls within', 'Longitude', 'Latitude', 'Location', 'LSOA code', 'LSOA name', 'Crime type']
    to_drop = ['No Location']

    for filename in glob.glob(os.path.join('<path>', '*.csv')):
            input_file_name.append(filename)

    for ifn in input_file_name:
        input_file.append(pd.read_csv(ifn, error_bad_lines=False, skipinitialspace=True, usecols=fields));

    frame = pd.concat(input_file, ignore_index=True)    
    frame = frame[~frame['Location'].isin(to_drop)]

    x, y = frame.iloc[:,:-1], frame.iloc[:, -1]
    x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, y, test_size=0.3, random_state=1)
```

The output of `frame.head()`

```
         Reported by          Falls within  Longitude   Latitude  \
0  Thames Valley Police  Thames Valley Police  -0.972323  51.991460   
1  Thames Valley Police  Thames Valley Police  -0.981511  51.997312   
2  Thames Valley Police  Thames Valley Police  -0.970516  51.992128   
3  Thames Valley Police  Thames Valley Police  -0.973412  51.992225   
4  Thames Valley Police  Thames Valley Police  -0.984120  51.997263   

                     Location  LSOA code            LSOA name  \
0      On or near Osprey Walk  E01017648  Aylesbury Vale 001A   
1  On or near Portfield Close  E01017648  Aylesbury Vale 001A   
2      On or near Lime Avenue  E01017648  Aylesbury Vale 001A   
3     On or near Martin Close  E01017648  Aylesbury Vale 001A   
4   On or near Mckenzie Close  E01017649  Aylesbury Vale 001B   

                  Crime type  
0      Anti-social behaviour  
1      Anti-social behaviour  
2                Other theft  
3              Vehicle crime  
4  Criminal damage and arson
```

Comment: Hve you tried it yet? I dont think that target (y) needs to be float.

Comment: Yes I did try it. Actually, target and some data values are also string let me add head of csv.

Comment: Other values (as in features in X) should not be string

Comment: Updated the question and added the CSV file. How to classify if strings are present as features?

Comment: You need to extract features from the strings. See available tutorials. See http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/feature_extraction.html

Comment: Thanks @VivekKumar for answering. But I'm having some problem in understanding this as I'm dealing with csv dataframe. Can the feature extraction deal with dataframe? Is there any efficient way to map the string with integers without manually doing it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder, OneHotEncoder, StandardScaler

y = frame['Crime type'].values
# convert the labels from strings to numbers (0,1,2....)
y = LabelEncoder().fit_transform(y)

frame = frame.drop(['Crime type'], axis=1)

for f in frame.columns:
    if frame[f].dtype == 'object':
        lbl_enc = LabelEncoder()
        # same as above encoding. it takes every object dtype from 
        # pandas dataframe and converts to numerical labels
        frame[f] = lbl_enc.fit_transform(frame[f].values)

X = frame.values
# binarize the encoded columns. this is not needed if you are using a tree based algorithm
ohe = OneHotEncoder(categorical_features=[0, 1, 4, 5, 6])
X = ohe.fit_transform(X)

# use the following for SVMs (with_mean=False for sparse data)
scl = StandardScaler(with_mean=False)
X = scl.fit_transform(X)
# fit model here: model.fit(X, y)
```

Comment: ValueError: Cannot center sparse matrices: pass `with_mean=False` instead. See docstring for motivation and alternatives.

Also, can you please explain what's happening?

Comment: Giving a memory error initiated at X = ohe.fit_transform(X)
The Error is too long to post here.

Comment: then remove `sparse=False` and the `StandardScaler` transformations

Comment: It's currently training. Thanks, I'll keep you posted. Could you explain what is actually happening?

Comment: I have added some comments. please accept the answer if it helped you.